# Generating combinations if items can be together in one combination just once

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinations, combinatorics

Let's say I have N items. Now I want to create M-item combinations but if there already exist a combination {A,B,C} (in this case M=3), then A cannot be in another combination together with B nor C.

Example: N={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, M=3, then possible combinations should be:

- {1,2,3}
- {4,5,6}
- {7,8,9}
- {10,1,2} - this is not a valid combination because 1 and 2 are already in a generated combination {1,2,3}
- {10,1,4}
- {2,5,8} - valid because all items were always in different combinations
- ...

**How many combinations I can create?**

**How could I systematically generate such combinations?**

**What if I allow that two items can be together in two different combinations?** So combinations {1,2,3} and {1,2,4} would be valid.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Thanks @IłyaBursov but I know to to create combinations. All of that wikipage is about creating k-combinations that allow in the result {A,B,C} as well as {A,B,D} but that's what I want to disallow since {A,B} is a subset of combination {A, B, C}.

Comment: You realize the solution to this will not be unique, as the order of consideration for the original elements matters...  If [1, 2, 4] were selected first, that would preclude [1, 2, 3].

Comment: Yes. I am actually looking for an optimal solution, just one solution will suffice. But I need the number of that combinations to be maximum possible and I don't want to use bruteforce or approximation algorithms.

Comment: I know I could generate all possible combinations and then test combinations one-by-one that they are valid and cutting them off the final solution. But it doesn't seem like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force, but pretty quick.  In `python`, but clear on approach, I believe:

```
from itertools import combinations as c

data = range(1,11)

already_seen = set()
result = set()

all_combos = c(data,3)

for combo in all_combos:
    pairs = set(c(combo, 2))
    if not pairs & already_seen:
        result.add(combo)
        already_seen.update(pairs)

print(result)

# {(3, 9, 10), (3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (2, 8, 10), (1, 4, 5), (2, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6), (1, 8, 9), (1, 6, 7), (3, 4, 7)}
```

Comment: Not optimal.  For 9 you get 8 combinations with `{(3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5), (2, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6), (1, 8, 9), (1, 6, 7), (3, 4, 7)}`.  But we can get 9 combinations with `{(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7), (3, 4, 8), (1, 6, 8), (2, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7)}`.

Comment: agreed....interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use standard combination generation algorithm, just add validation for used pairs, like this (in java, but pretty clear how to port to any other language):

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateCombinations(3, 10);
    }
    public static void generateCombinations(int m, int n) {
        var used = new HashSet<Long>();
        var combination = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) generateCombination(i, m, n, used, combination);
    }
    public static boolean generateCombination(int c, int m, int n, Set<Long> used, Set<Integer> comb) {
        for (Integer ci : comb) if (used.contains(getPair(ci.intValue(), c))) return false;
        boolean result = false;
        for (Integer ci : comb) used.add(getPair(ci.intValue(), c));
        comb.add(c);
        if (comb.size() < m) {
            for (int i = c + 1; i <= n; i++) {
                result |= generateCombination(i, m, n, used, comb);
                if (result && comb.size() >= 2) break;
            }
        } else {
            result = true;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(comb.toArray(new Integer[comb.size()])));
        }
        comb.remove(c);
        if (!result) for (Integer ci : comb) used.remove(getPair(ci.intValue(), c));
        return result;
    }
    public static long getPair(int a, int b) {
        return (((long) a) << 32L) | b;
    }
}
```

for 3-10 it generates 10 combinations and I suppose it is maximal number of subsets, feel free to prove me wrong

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 6, 7]
[1, 8, 9]
[2, 4, 6]
[2, 5, 7]
[2, 8, 10]
[3, 4, 7]
[3, 5, 6]
[3, 9, 10]
```

it should be moderately easy to extend it to support unique triplets instead of pairs, just generate string key like `min(a,b,c) + "_" + middle(a,b,c) + "_" + max(a,b,c)` instead of bitwise hack I used to speed up and add all from `comb` set into `used` set